# Allergies and Inflammation - Long term effects

Tags: allergy, inflammation

As I read about research on **inflammaging** (for example, [Fülöp et al 2019](https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/497375)), the link between chronic low-grade inflammation and the increased occurrence of age-related diseases, I wondered if there is a known connection between allergies and age-related diseases.
As far as I know, allergic reactions cause inflammations. So, in case one has a serious hay fever and suffers from inflammations in the nose, eyes, and skin for basically all summer, every year, I wondered if that would increase the risk of getting other inflammation-related conditions.

I couldn't find any research on this, so my questions are:

1. Is there anything obvious contradicting this hypothesis, or
2. does anybody know research or studies about this

---

[Fülöp, T., Larbi, A., & Witkowski, J. M. (2019). Human inflammaging. Gerontology, 65(5), 495-504.](https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/497375)

Comment: What is your source for the "fact" that chronic inflammation causes accelerated aging?

Comment: Hi, maybe it goes too far to call it a fact, but from tons of reviews, it seems at least strongly indicated that in many age-related diseases, such as Alzheimer's, you can at least say that inflammation is strongly linked with the occurrence of these diseases. 
Examples are: 
- https://www.karger.com/Article/FullText/497375
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00005-015-0377-3
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1044532318300228

Comment: @PeterO Hi, please [edit] these references into your question. Ideally you'd discuss them a bit, too, and weave them into your question. I've done this for one of your links as an example.